# React hook form how to pass value from custom component to controller with already assign own on change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm working on react-hook-form  need you guys help. I have my own component call "Input" So Just want to register with  but This Input component already assigned "Onclick" and "value" props so how to get Onchange and value to validate this input?

```
                          <Controller
                                    control={control}
                                    name="ProvinceInput"
                                    rules={{ required: true }}
                                    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
                                        <Input
                                            type="Province"
                                            onChange={setProvince}
                                            onSelect={onSelect}
                                            value={province}
                                            address={{
                                                province,
                                                amphoe,
                                                district,
                                                zipcode
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                />
{errors.ProvinceInput && <span className='mt-2 text-sm text-red-400' >This field is required</span>}
```

I follow on React-hook-form Docs
[image]
As you can see The component work fine but can't validate "ProvinceInput" That register. please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="ProvinceInput"
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
    <Input
      type="Province"
      onChange={e => {
        setProvince(e);
        onChange(e);
      }}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      value={province}
      address={{
        province,
        amphoe,
        district,
        zipcode,
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```